# PowerPoint 2007 - Programmatically insert data?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, bookmarks, powerpoint-2007

I know PowerPoint supports macros
But is there a way I can insert data from a datasource into a placeholder or something?
I've got a routine where I collect data from a database and store it in the registry. This data is then inserted into several Word templates. And this is working. 
But I can't find any bookmark support in PowerPoint and that's kinda how I insert data in Word templates. Can I select a certain placeholder or something in PowerPoint 2007 using macros?

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'll just answer this question myself :)
You can actually do this very easily in PowerPoint 2007 by using the CustomUIEditor.

Just open the template and insert this piece of code

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
onLoad="onLoadCode" >
</customUI>
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.